# customizing php session variable

Tags: php, session

I have been checking all post here but not get what i need.. i have multiple session variable,

some are for login information created once logged in:

```
$_SESSION['user']=$username; // Initializing Session user
$_SESSION['dept']='Admin'; // Initializing Session dept.
```

some are for the activity created in one of my page:

```
$_SESSION['actTxt1']=$_POST['actTxt1'];
$_SESSION['type2']=$_POST['type2'];
$_SESSION['level2']=$_POST['level2'];
$_SESSION['cogni1']=$_POST['cogni1'];
```

What if the activity is done and i want to clear all session created THERE but still i will not be logged out.

```
session_destroy();
```

when this is fire up, my session variable regarding my login info is destroyed also, is there any way i can retain it??

Comment: `session_destroy()` is pretty much the equivalent of `$_SESSION = array()`. if you want to retain parts of what's in $_SESSION, then you'd have to preserve them, call session_destroy, then restore the preserved things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a multidimensional array for the activity:

```
$_SESSION['activity']['actTxt1'] = $_POST['actTxt1'];
$_SESSION['activity']['type2'] = $_POST['type2'];
// etc...
```

Then just clear that array:

```
unset($_SESSION['activity']);
// or
$_SESSION['activity'] = array();
```

And actually, if you want all of the `$_POST` values in the session, then this is easier to add them:

```
$_SESSION['activity'] = $_POST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling session_destroy() will destroy all the available sessions. To destroy a specific session, you can use the unset() method like so:

```
unset($_SESSION['session_name']);
```